# Can we use filter while defining manytomanyfiled in django?

Tags: python, django, model, relationship, manytomanyfield

I have a user table with user type as actor, singer, producer etc.
I have another table Movies

```
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category =  models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='movies_category')
    release_date =  models.DateField()
    actors =  models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='movies_actors')           
    producer =  models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='movies_producers')
    singers =  models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='movies_singers')
    length =  models.TimeField()
```

when I create movie object then for actors fields only those user object should come which has user_type as actor and same for producer and other fields, how can I do that?
Or if that not possible please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may define a `ManyToManyField` with a [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) attribute. For example:

```py
actors = models.ManyToManyField(
    User, related_name='movies_actors', limit_choices_to={'user_type': 'actor'}
)
```